# Why do we use random sample with replacement while implementing random forest?

Tags: random-forest, bagging

Let's say we want to build random forest. Wikipedia says that we use random sample with replacement to do bagging. I don't understand why we can't use random sample without replacement.

Comment: You can, but then you would only permute the rows, the sample would be identical (by default we resample n times). If you resample less than n units then resampling without replacement can be a valid approach.

Comment: Two-part answer. First, definitorial answer: Since "bagging" means "bootstrap aggregation", you have to bootstrap, which is defined as sampling with replacement. Second, more interesting: Averaging predictors only improves the prediction if they are not overly correlated. The replacement reduces similarity of data, and hence correlation of predictions. If you magically are able to create little-correlated predictions, you don't have to sample with replacement. (Wouldn't be called "bagging" then.)

Answer (score 6):

Random forests are based on the concept of bootstrap aggregation (aka bagging). This is a theoretical foundation that shows that sampling with replacement and then building an ensemble reduces the variance of the forest without increasing the bias.

The same theoretical property is not true if you sample without replacement, because sampling without a replacement would lead to pretty high variance.

Let say we’re building a random forest with 1,000 trees, and our training set is 2,000 examples. If we sample without replacement we would train on 2 examples per tree. This is obviously impractical.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The real question is why you'd sample within a single "replicated dataset" with replacement. You can still train 1000 trees on a training set of 2000 samples. You can decide that for each learning dataset of 100 samples you draw, you do not replace those samples, such that you get 100 non-replicated samples for each tree you train.

Comment: Your example is even plain wrong, as the definition of bagging is that each learning dataset is equal in size to your full dataset. This means that you'd simply permute your samples and effectively create identical datasets for each tree.